# How to force ddclient to use only HTTPS?

Tags: https, dynamic-dns

I'm running [ddclient](https://github.com/ddclient/ddclient) on Arch Linux with Namecheap. I want to force ddclient to use only HTTPS.

Ddclient is a Perl client used to update dynamic DNS entries for accounts on 'Dynamic DNS Network Services' free DNS service.

In the file `/etc/ddclient/ddclient.conf` I have `ssl=yes`

I don't see another ddclient config setting related to this. Is there a way I can accomplish my goal?

Comment: have you put the `https://` in `use` line?  `use=web, web=https://....`

Comment: @binarysta I have not tried that because the docs don't show the protocol as part of the `use=web` config. Have you tried this and found it to work? I assume if it works it would be an undocumented feature.

Comment: yes adding `https` will make the client to connect over https.

Comment: @binarysta is this something you can turn into an Answer?